# Implementing HTML5shiv properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, html5shiv

After spending a while designing a website I've now decided I need to at least make it view-able in IE9 and below. I've followed examples from the below website:

https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv

but to no avail.

Here's how one of the sites pages looks in an up-to-date browser:
http://gyazo.com/10a74b651a216d76bb677d335fa1551d

And here's how it looks in IE9 and below:
http://gyazo.com/8541b263b9ed43e9d7dea9c33eafb22b

Strangely enough however, the homepage appears fine, it's just all of the others.

I implemented this code to the head of all of my html pages:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

html5shiv.js being in a folder called 'js' in my project directory.

And added this CSS code the my stylesheets:

```
/*HTML5*/
article, aside, details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
display:block; 
}
```

Even with this done, which I believe to be correct if I'm not being blind, IE9 and below don't display this site very well.

Any suggestions will be greatly welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` to `<!--[if lte IE 9]>`

Comment: You should probably read about what html5shiv _actually_ does. It's not a magical library that makes all your code work in older browsers; all it does is allow you to use HTML5 elements while keeping support for older browsers (eg, IE8 and below wouldn't even recognise `section` elements). It doesn't magically fix all the layout issues that those browsers suffer from. If you have a specific question about a specific piece of code that doesn't work in IE, please post it here (including the offending code), so that we can help you out.

Comment: I find it strange how, after removing all of the html5shiv code that my layout is still the same in IE9 and below, broken. Almost as if it did nothing. My header and footer displayed nicely on the home page, but on any other it would look how in did the in screenshot above even though the js code was implemented all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already figured this out Charlie but in case you haven't I would try these things...

***First, regarding the css:***

```
/*HTML5*/
article, aside, details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
display:block; 
}
```

↑ This should be included **before** your other css. Generally, you shouldn't need to do this as `HTML5shiv` already adds these styles, but for some older browsers or ones that have javascript disabled you could add these styles. It is easier in my opinion to just include [`normalize.css`](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css) in your `<head>` beforehand.

Also, make sure `HTML5shiv` is being added to the head (preferably at the end). If it's loaded in the footer after page load it could cause issues like the one you describe.

***Your code should look something like this:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title><meta name="description" content="">
    <!-- CSS Reset -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Your site CSS (Optional ) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim for support of HTML5 elements (added at end of head) -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

   You content here ....


  <!-- If you use javascript  -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are some known issues with html5shiv that can be found on the github page and if you still have issues you should report it [here](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv/issues). Also, make sure you are using the latest version of the script.

Comment: Also, hopefully we won't need these plugins much longer as the [older IE days are numbered](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support)!